# I Guess There's Some BIOS Problem

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

Heyy Awesome Community.
I need some help..
My laptop was getting slow day by day so i decided to install SSD in place of DVD drive in My Hp Laptop.

After installing the SSD i wanted to re-install UBUNTU on SSD. But after installation of Ubuntu i am not able to boot the device with SSD. The device is asking to enter a bootable drive again and again.

I don't know what's happening.

If i try to install Ubuntu again i can see the option of re-install Ubuntu along side Ubuntu.With some more options like Reinstall UBUNTU again and all

Comment: UEFI os BIOS/Legacy? That's the first distinction you need to know in order to understand the boot process requirements. Please update the question. Meanwhile there 's one particular "answer" you shouldn't follow.

Answer (score 0):

The bios on your laptop must pick a boot device.  Some systems allow this to be changed, others will only boot off of a single device.

If you have multiple disks in your laptop, you may have to install the ubuntu bootloader on the first disk, rather than the SSD.  The bootloader is fairly small, and having it on the slower disk will not affect system performance.

If you have an EFI based system and also have Windows, the EFI portion of the ubuntu bootloader should be installed in the same EFI partition that has the windows bootloader.